# Get value between delimiters in string using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like the Deparment value extracted from the string eg: COUNTRY_SITE_DEPARTMENT.csv, the DEPARTMENT between the "." and the "_" , im sure this is doable in SQL as a select query, can somebody point me in the right direction ?

I have used something similar to this from another example, but im out of luck :(

```
Select substring( LEFT(Col,charindex('.',Col)-1),
       charindex('_',Col)+1,
       len(LEFT(Col,charindex('.',Col)-1))-1 )
FROM FILENAMES;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i would like to apply a select statement to the table FILENAMES, so any db.

Comment: did u go through [this](http://www.berezniker.com/content/pages/sql/microsoft-sql-server/strextract-udf-retrieves-string-between-two-delimiters) may be it could help

Comment: I am not sure if you can do this database agnostic. 
In Oracle, I would make use of the instr function to find the ".", and then using that find the first "_" using the same function, except the in reverse mode. I would use those values for substr, with the necessary additions or subtractions. I would give you the statement, but I don't have access to Oracle now.

Comment: Looks like SQL Server to me...

Comment: I think you are right, based on substring and charindex.

Comment: Thanks to all, yeah i knew i wasnt far off :) Thanks again. Solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easiest to do if you reverse the string as you're looking for last `_`:

```
SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(Col), CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(Col)) + 1, 
        CHARINDEX('_', REVERSE(Col)) - CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(Col)) - 1))
FROM FILENAMES
```

I assumed SQL Server as you're using SQL Server functions in your query.